# How do I assign a two word label in an issue template?

Tags: gitlab

I've created an issue template for a user story. I have a label, "User Story." I would like to assign issues using the user story template the "User Story" label with the quick action syntax (/label ~label).

I've tried the following:

```
/label ~User Story
/label ~User+Story
```

Neither is working. I am assigning issues to single word labels successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Labels with spaces have to be enclosed with quotes.

So you have to write `/label ~"User Story"` in your issue template.